# python regex - characters between certain characters

Tags: python, regex, char, newline, regex-lookarounds

Edit: I should add, that the string in the test is supposed to contain every char there possible is (i.e. * + $ § € / etc.). So i thought of regexp should help best.

i am using regex to find all characters between certain characters([" and "]. My example goes like this:

```
test = """["this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char."], 
    ["another one after a newline."], 

    ["and another one even with
    newlines

    in it."]"""
```

The supposed output should be like this:

```
['this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char.', 'another one after a newline.', 'and another one even with newlines in it.']
```

My code including the regex looks like this:

```
import re
my_list = re.findall(r'(?<=\[").*(?="\])*[^ ,\n]', test)
print (my_list)
```

And my outcome is the following:

```
['this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char."]', 'another one after a newline."]', 'and another one even with']
```

so there are two problems:

1) its not removing `"]` at the end of a text as i want it to do with `(?="\])`

2) its not capturing the third text in brackets, guess because of the newlines. But so far i wasnt able to capture those when i try `.*\n` it gives me back an empty string.

I am thankful for any help or hints with this issue. Thank you in advance.

Btw iam using python 3.6 on anaconda-spyder and the newest regex (2018).

EDIT 2: One Alteration to the test:

```
test = """[
    "this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char."
    ], 
    [
    "another one after a newline."
    ], 

    [
    "and another one even with
    newlines

    in it."
    ]"""
```

Once again i have trouble to remove the newlines from it, guess the whitespaces could be removed with \s, so an regexp like this could solve it, i thought.

```
my_list = re.findall(r'(?<=\[\S\s\")[\w\W]*(?=\"\S\s\])', test)
print (my_list)
```

But that returns only an empty list. How to get the supposed output above from that input?

Comment: `The supposed output should be like this` So you want to remove newlines in the output in addition to matching? Looks like you'll need a `.sub` or something as well

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this mate.**

```
(?<=\[\")[\w\s.]+(?=\"\])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mr7SBX/1)

What you missed in your regex `.*` will not match newline.

**P.S** I am not matching special characters. if you want it can be achieved very easily.

This one matches special characters too

`(?<=\[\")[\w\W]+?(?=\"\])`

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Mr7SBX/2)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes i want to include basically every character there is. I thought '.' would include every character besides newline but i guess it just stops when it hits newline.
Btw is there a way to get rid of those \n in the output now? And also the additional whitespace in between (...with\n        newlines...)?
I know how to get rid of it using replace with a for loop but if its possible to get it done in the regexp, id like to know.

Comment: @MikeTwain Yes you can.Check answer i have updated. If it helped you can select this answer as correct one :p

Comment: thanks. Although the output still contains those \n characters. No way to get rid of them as well?
Btw one last alteration, if i may. I edited it in my question. Alteration to test.

Comment: i wanted to match everything between [" and "]. btw i just edited the question.

Comment: @MikeTwain yes mate you can.  result.replace(/(?:\n+|\s{2,})/, ' ') use this regex you will get your desired output

Comment: re has no method replace (only sub). how is it supposed to work?
Also the previous method findall doesnt work anymore in my altered example.

Comment: @MikeTwain yeah you can use sub. sorry i am now a days using JS a lot so :p

Answer (score 1):

In case you might also accept not regex solution, you can try

```
result = []
for l in eval(' '.join(test.split())):
    result.extend(l)

print(result)
#  ['this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char.', 'another one after a newline.', 'and another one even with newlines in it.']
```

Comment: interesting approach, havnt thought about that so far. But it seems to work quiet well for my example. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I came up:

```
test = """["this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char."], 
    ["another one after a newline."], 

    ["and another one even with
    newlines

    in it."]"""

for i in test.replace('\n', '').replace('    ', ' ').split(','):
    print(i.lstrip(r' ["').rstrip(r'"]'))
```

Which results in the following being printed to the screen

```
this is a text and its supposed to contain every possible char.
another one after a newline.
and another one even with newlines in it.
```

If you want a list of those -exact- strings, we could modify it to-

```
newList = []
for i in test.replace('\n', '').replace('    ', ' ').split(','):
  newList.append(i.lstrip(r' ["').rstrip(r'"]'))
```